# Validate email id length using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email

I have regex to validate my emails as follows.

```
^[\w-\._\+%]+@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w]{2,6}$
```

It is working fine for me. I want to validate minumum and maximum length of email within above regex. So, I have write same regex with nominal changes as follows.

```
^[[\w-\._\+%]+@(?:[\w-]+\.)+[\w]{2,6}]{5,50}$
```

I want min. length of email is 5 and max. length upto 50 characters. The above regex doesn't work for me. I don't know where is the mistek.

Can some one guide me to get desired output?

Thanks

Comment: Don't use regex for this. Just use [string.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length)

Comment: thanks @RGraham, That is also i can do. but if possible in single validation is the best for me. :)

Comment: Don't use regex for emails either...

Answer (score 0):

As RGraham has said, this is better done with `.length`.

However, if you have some requirement (such as using the HTML5 form attribute `pattern`), you could do this:

```
/^(?=.{5,50})REST OF REGEX HERE$/
```

I'd also like to point out that parsing emails with regex is almost as bad of an idea as parsing HTML with regex... almost.

Instead, just use:

```
<input type="email" />
```

The browser will handle validation for you ;)

Comment: hi @Niet, I can not getting you clearly. can you please make a full/complete  regex for me? It is very helpful to me.

Comment: I'd rather not do that, because as I keep saying, regex is NOT the right tool to be using here ;)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple regex for email validation is

```
/^([^\s@"]+@)([\w]+\.[\w]+)$/
```

which required **minimum 5 character** i.e. a@b.c then u juz need to check its max length by **string.length<50 condition**.

here ther's no need of minimum check.

I have made very simple validator if you want enhanced validator then you can specify your needs(validations) so i can help you.

I hope this will help you.